# Can not use UserAdmin fildsets with cutom user model

Tags: django, django-models

I tried to customize Django User,which worked fine but I lost things like user_permissions.
I don't have user permissions window from which I can give permissions like "can add Product,Can delete cart" etc.
I tried this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('email', 'staff')}),
```

and

```
UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('email', 'staff')}),
```

but these didn't worked for me.
If I try to add 'user_permissions' to fieldsets I get error
" Unknown field 'user_permissions' specified'".

Do I need to define user_permissions fields?

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password=None,is_active=True,is_staff=False,is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have password")
        user_obj = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.set_password(password)  #inbuild hashing
        user_obj.save(using = self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email,password=password,is_staff=True)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email,password=password,is_staff=True,is_admin=True)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email    = models.EmailField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    # full_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # confirmed= models.BooleanField(default=False) #confirmed email?

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
```

This is how my admin looks currently.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [**`PermissionsMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin) class while creating the custom user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # your fields
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) When I did this and migrated, I got 3 extra columns 'groups','user_permissions' and one more. I added 'user_permissions' to fieldsets .